# Assertion Failed in C++ questions

Tags: c++

when we want to disable assertion we have to define NDEBUG but why should we define it before the inclusion of assert header file??
the second question: what is the point in disabling assertion and using the macro assert??

Comment: You enable asserts when debugging, and disable in production.

Comment: it is better to define NDEBUG by add -DNDEBUG (or something similar) to compiler flag  so you don't need change code

Comment: defining NDEBUG does it mean that we are switching to RELEASE mode???

Comment: I think that some confusion here follows from the fact that on unix you usually define NDEBUG, while VC++ (IIRC) defines _DEBUG

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean? as i know vc++ uses #define _DEBUG for debug mode and disable assertion using #define NDEBUG. the question I'm confused with is: "Disabling Assertion does it mean switching to release mode???" if so why shouldn't we remove assertions directly from a release code??

Comment: You do know that using additional question marks doesn't improve your question in the slightest, don't you? The obvious reason for not removing assertions from a release build is that you'd have to write them all back in the next time you wanted to make a debug build. The whole point of defining `NDEBUG` is precisely to avoid you having to do that, so you can leave them in there, but have them omitted from the compiled code during a release build without having to change the source.

Comment: ok. thak you for your thourough explaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when we want to disable assertion we have to define NDEBUG but why should we define it before the inclusion of assert header file??

Because `assert` is defined [similarly to the following code fragment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert):

```
#ifdef NDEBUG

#define assert(condition) ((void)0)
#else
#define assert(condition) /*implementation defined*/
#endif
```

Now the condition will only be true if `NDEBUG` has been defined beforehand.

> the second question: what is the point in disabling assertion and using the macro assert?

Assertions cost runtime. You still want them to hold in a released product, but you don't want to check them. For example:

```
auto a = b;
assert(a == b);
```

If the equality test takes much time it is something you want to avoid in a productive environment. However, while debugging/testing it's good to know that the first line actually produces a copy that's equal to the original object.

All in all you use `assert()` to, well, assert something while developing/debugging, and when this assertions hold during the tests, you can safely disable them for release.

Comment: ok well. so could we write: #ifdef _DEBUG #include<cassert> #else #define NDEBUG #include <cassert> #endif void main(){ assert(7==0);}//I want to check wether we are on cebug mode or release mode

Comment: @ProDev7: Why do you even want to do that? In release mode, any `assert()` will be gone.